# How do I write a loop function that will make separate scatterplots graphs all in one go? Also how do I add a line of best fit?

Tags: python, loops, regression, finance

I know how to make separate scatterplots, but I want them all in one view positioned next to each other side by side. I also want to add a line of best fit for each graph in this view. I am comparing all of these stock tickers to the SPY index and showing a regression. Thank you!

I tried putting things into an array and creating subplots but that didn't work so now I am stuck.

```py
import yfinance as yf, matplotlib.pyplot as plt, numpy as np

import pandas_datareader.data as reader 

import statsmodels.api as sm

import seaborn as sns

import pandas as pd

from scipy import stats

from dateutil.relativedelta import *

import getFamaFrenchFactors as gff

import datetime 

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

import pandas as pd

from xbbg import blp


tickers = ['JPM', 'C', 'BAC', 'MS', 'GS', 'WFC', 'BCS']

weights  = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

today1= datetime.date.today() 
olddate1 = today1 - datetime.timedelta(weeks=26.5)

df_spy = yf.download('SPY', olddate1, today1)['Adj Close']
                      
today= datetime.date.today()
olddate = today - datetime.timedelta(weeks=26.5)

df = yf.download(tickers, olddate, today)['Adj Close']

fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10), nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)
Scatter1=ax[0].scatter(x=df_spy.pct_change(), y = df[tickers[0]].pct_change(), c=)


plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[0]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[1]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[2]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[3]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[4]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[5]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)

plt.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(),df[tickers[6]].pct_change(), alpha =.6, color='blue', s=55)
```

Comment: as I remember it should get `ax` as parameter - something like `plt.scatter( ax=ax[0], ..)` `plt.scatter( ax=ax[1], ..)`, etc. But you create `plt.subplots(.., nrows=2, ncols=1, ..)` so you have place only for 2 chars. You would have to create more rows or columns

Answer (score 0):

With current code you could use `plt.subplots(..., nrows=2, ncols=7, ...)` to have more places for plots, and later use `ax[0][0].scatter()`, `ax[0][1].scatter()`, ... , `ax[1][6].scatter()` to put plots side by side

Full working code:

```
import datetime 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


tickers = ['JPM', 'C', 'BAC', 'MS', 'GS', 'WFC', 'BCS']

weights = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

today = datetime.date.today() 

olddate = today - datetime.timedelta(weeks=26.5)
df_spy = yf.download('SPY', olddate, today)['Adj Close']
df = yf.download(tickers, olddate, today)['Adj Close']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10), nrows=2, ncols=7, sharex=True)

ax[0][0].scatter(x=df_spy.pct_change(), y=df[tickers[0]].pct_change())
ax[0][0].set_title('SPY')

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

for index, item in enumerate(tickers):
    ax[1][index].scatter(df_spy.pct_change(), df[item].pct_change(), alpha=.6, color='blue', s=55)
    ax[1][index].set_title(item)

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But this gives empty places.

[image]

---

Using `plt.subplot(rows, cols, index)` you can better control plots and create one bigger plot (above) and many small plots (below).

```
import datetime 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


tickers = ['JPM', 'C', 'BAC', 'MS', 'GS', 'WFC', 'BCS']

weights = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])

today = datetime.date.today() 

olddate = today - datetime.timedelta(weeks=26.5)
df_spy = yf.download('SPY', olddate, today)['Adj Close']
df = yf.download(tickers, olddate, today)['Adj Close']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)  # (rows, cols, index)
ax.scatter(x=df_spy.pct_change(), y=df[tickers[0]].pct_change())
ax.set_title('SPY')

plt.rcParams['axes.grid'] = False

for index, item in enumerate(tickers):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, 7, index+1+7)  # (rows, cols, index)
    ax.scatter(df_spy.pct_change(), df[item].pct_change(), alpha=.6, color='blue', s=55)
    ax.set_title(item)

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]